Javascript object function, calling from outside
I have created a JavaScript object that includes functions within the object.
I want to know if it is possible to call one of these functions from outside.
In this case, I want to call "fn_populate_team()" from outside the object.
I know I can create individual functions outside the object but I am curious to see if the what I have asked is possible?


league = [];
    league[0] = [];
    league[0][0]    = {};
    
    league[0][0].fn_build_team_details = function(edit, division){
        function fn_build_blank_team(callback_1){
            league[0][0].divison = division;
            league[0][0].team = [];
            league[0][0].team[0] = [];
            for(n=0; n<=3; n++){
                league[0][0].team[0][n] = {};
                league[0][0].team[0][n].gate        = n;
                league[0][0].team[0][n].rider       = [0];
                league[0][0].team[0][n].team_pts    = [0];
            };
            callback_1(division);
        };
        function fn_populate_team(divi){
            console.log("<br/>Populate League "+divi+"<br/>");
        };
        
        fn_build_blank_team(fn_populate_team);
        return this;
    };
    
    league[0][0].fn_build_team_details(0,  1);
    
    // Call fn_populate_team() that is inside the object //




You can’t unless you return a reference for it

Variables defined in a function are not available outside the function unless you return them from the function.

any reason why you are not going for a class with constructor?
